# replace \N in csv dump of a sql file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I use the following to dump a sql file in csv format : 
$file_path = "/tmp/app_users.csv";

```
    $sql = "SELECT 'id','username','name','email',
        'phone_number','city',
        'batch_code','course_type' UNION ALL
        SELECT id, username, name, email,
        phone_number, city, batch_code, course_type
        FROM users INTO OUTFILE '".$file_path."' ".
            "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            ENCLOSED BY '\"'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";

    $db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
    $stmt = $db->query($sql, array());
```

But certain fields in the users table are null, which in the csv output is shown as \N. I want it to be replaced with a string "NULL". I tried to use str_replace, but it mysteriously inserts an extra blank line after every line.

Comment: If the FIELDS ESCAPED BY character is empty (in your query), no characters are escaped and NULL is output as NULL, not \N. [See official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the [FIELDS ESCAPED BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) character is empty (in your query), no characters are escaped and NULL is output as NULL, not \N.

So following should give you desired result:

```
$sql = "SELECT 'id','username','name','email',
    'phone_number','city',
    'batch_code','course_type' UNION ALL
    SELECT id, username, name, email,
    phone_number, city, batch_code, course_type
    FROM users INTO OUTFILE '".$file_path."' ".
        "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        ENCLOSED BY '\"'
        ESCAPED BY ''
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";
```

It's just one way to do it and you might not want to use this if you need other characters escaped.

Comment: @SonuJha Sorry, pasted it wrong. Corrected the query in the answer. Works for me.